# How to determine a query for a specific time interval in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running some `crontabs` which trigger `R-Scripts` where I load `Google Analytics Data` for a specific time interval. Usually its the interval:

`Today - 1 to Today - 14 days` which corresponds to the following statement:

`subset(mydata, date >= Sys.Date()-14 & date <= Sys.Date()-1)`

I would like to add some `MySQL-Query` to that `R-Script`in order to get some data, which uses the same time interval. My tables have the following form:

```
`pictures`                     `music`                `likes`

 id  date_of_upload         id   pictures_id          id   pictures_id

 1    2012-01-16              50       1283           287    12
 2    2012-02-17              25       736            2366   39
 ...  ...                     ...      ...            ...    ...
 6000 2016-01-23
```

My query has the following form where I would like to meet the upper time interval:

```
SELECT 
      COUNT(p.id) AS pictures,
      COUNT(m.id) AS songs,
      COUNT(l.id) AS likes,
      CAST(p.date_of_upload AS DATE) AS Posted


FROM pictures p
      LEFT JOIN
       music m ON p.id = m.pictures_id
      LEFT JOIN
       likes l ON p.id = l.pictures_id
WHERE p.date_of_upload > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL - 14 DAY)
```

But that doesn't seem to be the right implementation for the time interval.

The required output may look as following:

```
 posted      songs   likes  picture

2016-01-23    20      30    3
2016-01-22    10      8     1
2016-01-21 
...
2016-01-07
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.id) AS pictures,
       COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) AS songs,
       COUNT(DISTINCT l.id) AS likes,
       CAST(p.date_of_upload AS DATE) AS Posted
FROM pictures p LEFT JOIN
     music m
     ON p.id = m.pictures_id LEFT JOIN
     likes l
     ON p.id = l.pictures_id
WHERE p.date_of_upload > DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL - 14 DAY)
```

The problem is probably that you are getting Cartesian products between the two tables -- a separate row for each combination of pictures, music, and likes.

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` is the easiest way, but if you have large values, then it is inefficient.

Comment: If you want to add the indicated time interval (Today - 1 to Today - 14 days), you can use between: `WHERE p.date_of_upload between DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL - 1 DAY) and DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL - 14 DAY)`

Comment: @ Capile  I have thought about `between`but was not able to properly include it. Thank you!